# javascript - simplify: if Var is empty-ish then "", else enclose Var with text

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I am writing es templates.
I want to make the codes as simple as possible and at best avoid using (function(){return XXX})()

The context: When a list has nothing, prints nothing, otherwise prints the list with ul tags around.

```
${
  // same filter 2 times
  arr.filter( d=>d.prop1=="a" ).length==0
    ? ""
    : `<ul> ${ arr.filter( d=>d.prop1=="a" ).map(d=>`<li>${d.text}</li>`) } </ul>`
}
```

or

```
${
  // function makes it bulky
  (function(){
    let arr2 = arr.filter( d=>d.prop1=="a" );
    if( arr2.length == 0 ){
      return ""
    }else{
      return `<ul> ${ arr2.map(d=>`<li>${d.text}</li>`) } </ul>`
    }
  })()
}
```

one more context, sometimes the problem is like this:

```
 const NAMES = [
   { name:"John" },
   { name:"Michael", nickname:"Mike" },
 ];

 NAMES.map( n=>`name: ${n.name} ${ n.nickname? "("+n.nickname+")":"" }` ).join("\n")
 // can simplify n.nickname? "("+n.nickname+")":"" ?
```

Anyone come up with a way to simplify these? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `array.some` is a bit faster than checking the length of the filtered array.

```js
${
    ARR.some(o => !!o.attr) 
    ? `<ul>${ARR.filter(o => !!o.attr).map(o => (`<li>${o.attr}</li>`))}</ul>` 
    : ""
}
```

Also, since most templates don't print `false` value, you can simplify with `&&`.

```js
${ ARR.some(o => !!o.attr) && `<ul>${ARR.filter(o => !!o.attr).map(o => (`<li>${o.attr}</li>`))}</ul>` }
```

If you do not want to maintain the duplicated condition, using a variable is necessary, so I don't know any other way rather than using a function. Using the tricks from above, you can reduce the function size a bit.

```
${
    ((arr) => {
        arr = arr.filter(o => !!o.attr);
        return !!arr.length && `<ul>${arr.map(o => (`<li>${o.attr}</li>`))}</ul>`;
    })(ARR)
}
```

For `NAMES`, you can just use backsticks.

```js
NAMES.map(o => (`Name: ${o.name}${o.nickname ? ` (${o.nickname})` : ""}`))
```

Comment: There is still the filter function part needed to be maintained twice.If there are no more answers, I will mark this as answer.

Comment: `filter` runs for the whole array. `some` runs till the first match. There's only one `filter` function called here. The `o => !!o.attr` part is just a condition arrow function for `some` or `filter`.

Comment: If you don't want to maintain the duplicated condition, I guess using a function is the only way. Using the tricks from before, you can reduce the size of the function quite a bit. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `filter` value to `object` and then apply `length` in condition part of `?:`. Then you can use that `object` in `true` part to get `map`.

Your code will look like below.

```
(a = arr.filter(d => d.prop1 == "a")).length ? `<ul> ${ a.map(d=>`<li>${d.prop1}</li>`) } </ul>` : "";
```

Try it below.

```js
function getTemplate(arr) {
  return (a = arr.filter(d => d.prop1 == "a")).length ? `<ul> ${ a.map(d=>`<li>${d.prop1}</li>`) } </ul>` : "";
}

console.log(getTemplate([{prop1: 'a'}])); // output : <ul> <li>a</li> </ul>
console.log(getTemplate([{prop1: 'b'}])); // output :
```

---

Similarly with `NAMES`

1. Use (n.nickname || "") which will return "" in case of value is `null` or `undefined`.
2. At last replace `()` with `''` so if there is no nickname then it would have () at end and we can remove it with replace.

```js
const NAMES = [{
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    name: "Michael",
    nickname: "Mike"
  },
];

// Use (n.nickname || "") which will return "" in case of value is null or undefined. 
// At last replace () with empty string so if there is no nickname then it would have () at end and we can remove it with replace.
let result = NAMES.map(n => `name: ${n.name} ${"(" + (n.nickname || "") + ")" }`.replace(' ()', '')).join("\n");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! It is OK but I think I do not love to maintain the replacing content.

Comment: hmm... the ( tempvar = filter() ) is the neatest code, however, it will not work under "use strict" and tempvar is created as a byproduct. Still, your answer has inspired me, thanks!